# ios facebook sdk 4.28.0 login error code 3

Tags: ios, facebook, authentication

I use the following method to log in, and always return:

> Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Unknown error building URL.}.

```
     FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login
     logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"]
     fromViewController:self
     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"facebook login result.grantedPermissions = %@,error = %@",result.grantedPermissions,error);
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Process error");
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Logged in");
         }
     }];
```

Comment: show your plist

Comment: You can download the plist file from this link.     [link](https://pan.baidu.com/s/1o9pYWvo)

Comment: Please check my answer to the similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/53695839/5093900