# ios facebook login sdk 4.28.0 error code 3

Tags: ios, facebook-login

[image: Info.plist has been configured]
Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Unknown error building URL.}

The login code is as follows

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

    [login
     logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile"]
     fromViewController:self
     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         NSLog(@"facebook login result.grantedPermissions = %@,error = %@",result.grantedPermissions,error);
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Process error");
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Logged in");
         }
     }];
```

Comment: can you post your login code???

Comment: @AshwinShrestha  I've already post the code.

Comment: did you try it with different facebook accounts? Also try to delete the login under facebook --> apps

Comment: @Steeve  When I click on the login, it do not jump to the login page

Comment: so you couldn't even enter email and password?

Comment: @Steeve   Yes, the problem is as you say

Comment: I am facing same problem after upgrading pod 4.39.0. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 7):

Encountered the same error today, after upgrading to version 4.39.0. 
Downgrading to 4.38.0 resolved it.

Comment: I second that! Same problem, same solution.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue after migration from ver. 4.38.1 to 4.39.0.

The reason is In FBSDKInternalUtility.m `+(NSURL *)URLWithScheme:host:path:queryParameters:error:`
method is trying to create NSURL from string which is containing "{", "}" symbols.

This is happening because FBSDKUtility.m `+(NSString *) URLEncode:`
method was changed. To fix it it is enough to add "{", "}" symbols to argument string:

```
NSCharacterSet *urlAllowedSet = [NSCharacterSet
                                   characterSetWithCharactersInString:@" !*();:'@&=+$,/?%#[]\"{}"].invertedSet;
```

I'm not sure this will not break another functionality. So **it's better to just use previous version of SDK**.

Comment: I tried changing *urlAllowedSet to the line you suggested, but it didn't help. I would be glad to use previous version but I'm using FirebaseUI.

Comment: You could try to use method from ver. 4.38.1:
`+ (NSString *)URLEncode:(NSString *)value
{
  NSCharacterSet *urlAllowedSet = [NSCharacterSet URLFragmentAllowedCharacterSet];
  return [value stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:urlAllowedSet];
}`

Or to check if there is appearing non-URL symbols here: `+(NSURL *)URLWithScheme:host:path:queryParameters:error:`.

Answer (score 4):

If you downgrade to FBSDKCoreKit & FBSDKLoginKit to 4.38.0 and still get this error make sure you clean your build.

```
Open your workspace
Command + Option + Shift + K
```

Mine works with the following pod versions. I will test with 4.38 and 0.5 and update.

pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.36.0'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.36.0'
pod 'FacebookCore', '0.4'
pod 'FacebookLogin', '0.4'

Comment: Thanks! I had a hard time making it work with 0.5 Swift libs and >4.39 ObjcC dependencies. This combo worked just fine.

Comment: @gercilasun. I'm having that error on FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKLoginKit 4.39, but downgrading to 4.3 made fail the build for the error: `Firebase Auth Interop/FIRAuth Interop.h' file not found` in the `FIRAuth.m `#import <FirebaseAuthInterop/FIRAuthInterop.h>`line.
Any idea? haven't tried downgrading to 4.36 dough.

Answer (score 3):

It's a kind of bug in latest '4.39.0', you just need to lower one version, i.e., '4.38.1'. 'pod' file will look like below:

```
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.38.1'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.38.1'
```

Once you install the 'pod', make sure you clean the project.

> Update:

In case, if you are not using the pods then you can download the old frameworks from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/downloads and just drag and drop in the project.

Comment: I'm seeing this bug and I don't use cocoapods. Any suggestions?

Comment: @anthonyhumphreys Yes, why not, please check the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

For those who using FirebaseUI - solution is similar. Put extra lines in Podfile:

```
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '4.38.1'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '4.38.1'
```

This will force downloading older libraries instead of new ones

Answer (score -1):

Did you implement this method in your AppDelegate?

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                                                          openURL:url
                                                sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                                                       annotation:annotation];
}
```

Comment: I have implemented this method