# Downgrading Facebook SDK for iOS 9 application

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

Referring to the question here

[ios facebook login sdk 4.28.0 error code 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49124804/ios-facebook-login-sdk-4-28-0-error-code-3/66529118)

I am facing the same issue. Trying to run the app on iOS 9 device, I receive the same error. The problem now is that the required versions are not available as Cocoapods. Tried to update using GitHub link I got the attached error.

Thanks
[image: Package resolution failed]

Comment: It looks like you are trying to add it as a Swift Package. The Facebook SDK is only available as a package for version 5.10.0 and above, see their documentation [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk#swift-package-manager-available-xcode-112-and-forward). If you wish to use an older version that does not support packages then you would have to use CocoaPods. From the Facebook SDK [podspec it says that it supports iOS 9 and up](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/c680200adede90040a1a4efef9dae84ff9c516f8/FacebookSDK.podspec#L21)